# Why Task doesn't return null

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm working with the new [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and today went to this case:

This code doesn't compile:

```
    internal Task<Guid?> SavePages(string[] pages)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (pages == null || pages.Length == 0)
                return null;

            ....
```

Unless I explicitly returns a null nullable Guid:

```
    internal Task<Guid?> SavePages(string[] pages)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (pages == null || pages.Length == 0)
                return (Guid?)null;

            // Check documents path access
```

Why this behavior, I'm I doing something wrong? I mean, I get the code to work with the second option but don't know If I'm misusing the library, I mean, null is always null, isn't it?

Compile error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
>   'System.Func' because some of the return
>   types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate
>   return type

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: FFR, including the exact compiler error would be useful, since in this case it likely mentions something about not being able to infer the type.

Comment: The problem is that null is always null, so the compiler have no way of knowing which type you are representing with your null expression

Comment: Side note: two other ways to express the same thing as `(Guid?)null` are `new Guid?()` and `default(Guid?)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the way the compiler determines the type of your lambda. When you return a plain `null`, the only thing the compiler can imply is that you are returning an object. Hence, your parameterless lambda is compatible with `Task<object>`. However, the signature of your function says that you are returning `Task<Guid?>`, so the return type the compiler implied from your code is not compatible. When you cast that `null` to `Guid?`, you provide the compiler a the clue it is missing to make the lambda a `Task<Guid?>`.

Comment: The compiler should really deduce this on its own (although it's quite clear why it doesn't)

Comment: @zmbq how would you determine what type `null` has? it's a valid value for all reference types so there's no way the compiler can determine the type of that expression (to anything other than object)

Comment: @RuneFS Given that it's a nullable type then assign must work, don't you agre?

Comment: The type can be deduced from the type of the SavePages.

Comment: @zmbq That's not how type inference works in C#. Usually, the type of each expression is inferred independently (lambdas are an exception, though).

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation with type inference in the C# compiler. This issue is not unrelated to the one involving the ternary operator:

```
int? num = a != null ? a.Value : null;         // Will not compile
int? num = a != null ? a.Value : (int?)null;   // Compiles
int? num = a != null ? (int?)a.Value : null;   // Compiles
```

Another workaround for your specific situation is to specify the generic type explicitly:

```
return Task.Run<Guid?>(() =>
{
    if (pages == null || pages.Length == 0)
        return null;
```

Comment: +1 Douglas for the explanation. One question: Does using the non generic version of Task.Run (as you suggest) decrease performance in any possible way?

Comment: unless I'm missing something, he's just talking about not making the compiler infer the type - either way you get the same generated IL AFAICT

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul: My code still uses the generic version of [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); in fact, it does so *explicitly*, as opposed to inferring the type (as your code does). Like James Manning said, I don’t believe there will be any difference in the generated IL, since type inference is performed at compile-time. Specifying the generic type explicitly might make compilation (*not* runtime) marginally faster, but this is something you’ll almost certainly never need to consider.